# loop em json em flask usando render_template

Tags: python, json, flask

Olá, eu tenho o seguinte json:

```
{"movies": "[{\"title\":\"Hercules\",\"rep\":99.96},{\"title\":\"In the Dark\",\"rep\":98.12},{\"title\":\"Titas\",\"rep\":96.61}]"}
```

e gostaria de percorrer ele jogando em uma tabela no html usando o render template do flask, ficou dessa forma:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
      <h1>Flask</h1>

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Rep</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {% for movie in movies %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ movie.rep }}</td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      
</body>

</html>
```

porém eu tenho como resultado o seguinte:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: o json foi gerado atraves de um dataframe utilizando o seguinte codigo:

```
m = df[['title','rep']].head(3).to_json(orient='records')
movies={'movies':m}
return render_template('index.html',movies=json.dumps(movies))
```

o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O primeiro problema é que você está passando uma `string` para o método `render_template` ao usar o `json.dumps`. Você também não precisa converter o dataframe para json e depois em dicionário, daria para usar o método `to_dict`.

Além disso você poderia passar a lista diratamente no parâmetro, não precisaria adicionar ela a um dicionário.

Então, dessa maneira seu template deve funcionar como o esperado:

```py
movies = df[['title','rep']].head(3).to_dict(orient='records')
return render_template('index.html', movies=movies)
```